# Using UsageStatsManager to get applications usage for the given time range not working

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I'm trying to get the application usage using the UsageStatsManager. It's actually working just fine if I try to get from any day till today, meaning that the`endTime` is today. But if I try to select a range that finishes before today it's not working